# Find $3$d vector from latitude, longitude and radius

Tags: vectors, spherical-coordinates

I basically would like to know how to find $P$ if you have $\phi$ and $\theta$ and the radius being $1$. Just like in the diagram below...

[image]

Comment: There is no theta in the diagram. It's also unclear what you mean by "finding P": if you mean "find its x,y,z coordinates", you'll need to specify the axes as well.

Comment: Try [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates)